# React state undefined after setState?

Tags: reactjs

I have a handler that fires upon change in the input field. However, when I log the state to the console resData is 'undefined'? It's impossible because console.log(body) does return results.

```
handlePersonNameChange(event) {
var resData
request('https://swapi.co/api/people/?search='+event.target.value, function (error,response,body) {
  console.log(body)
  resData = body
})
this.setState({personData: resData});
console.log(this.state)
}
```

Comment: You should set the state inside the request callback. Also, setting state in React is asynchronous, so you can't `setState()` then `console.log(this.state)` on the next line and expect to see the state updated.

Comment: In this case, I get TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Answer (score 5):

A request call is asynchrone, you should put the `this.setState` within the response body.

Also `this.setState` is asynchrone, to see the result you should use the callback function. This funciton is called after the new state is set.

```
handlePersonNameChange(event) {
  var resData
  request('https://swapi.co/api/people/?search='+event.target.value, 
  function (error,response,body) {
    console.log(body)
    resData = body
    this.setState({personData: resData}, function() {
      console.log(this.state)
    })
  })
}
```

More info about `this.setState()` can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `setState` inside the request callback, for example :

```
request('https://swapi.co/api/people/?search='+event.target.value, function (error,response,body) {
  console.log(body)
  resData = body
  this.setState({personData: resData});
})
```

because your request hasn't resovled when you do `setState` in your example.

Comment: In this case, I get TypeError: this.setState is not a function.

Comment: That's because your callback isn't binded. You can use an arrow function (if you have ES6 support) (error, response, body) => { this.setState({personData: body}) }

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({ state : "new1" })
```

This method is not synchronous so when you are logging the state it is not yet updated.

You should log it in componentWillUpdate lifecycle method.